# MS Access - 2 Different Page Footers

Tags: database, ms-access

I am working with a MS Access database that has several reports built into it. Each report, has up to 3 subreports built into the the middle of the report.

The setup of the report is as follows:

```
Page header <blank>
UserGroup Header <blank>
Report Detail <report data and up to 3 subreports>
UserGroup Footer <more data>
Page Footer <footer data>
```

What I would like to achieve, if possible, is 2 different Page Footers. One footer for the main report and a different footer for the subreports. While I know the way the report is currently setup is most likely not a very efficient way to have done it (db was passed down two me as is), but for me to fix the issue, I would have to rebuild approx. 16 reports, so i would like to explore all options before going down that road.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a light bulb go off in my head after staring at this post for a while.

I found a workaround by creating a page counter in the Page Footer, then making the text box not visible and using VB to write an if based on the page number to hide one footer and show the other.

Ill leave the question/answer posted as I could not find a workaround for this issue.